# Button click event not fire properly in <include> tag in ANDROID

Tags: android

I have three XML files are

1) Header
2) FirstActivity
3) SecondActivity.

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button 
android:text="Button 1" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="first1"
>
</Button>

<Button 
android:text="Button 2" 
android:id="@+id/button2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="second"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**firstactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<include layout="@layout/headerfile"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Phone Detail"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/simid"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/imeino"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/phoneno"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />  
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**HeaderActivity.java**

```
public class HeaderActivity extends Activity {
Button b1,b2;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.headerfile);


b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2) ;

} //onCreate over

public void first1(View v)
{
Intent i =new Intent(this,firstactivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();       
}

public void second(View v)
{
Intent i1 =new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
startActivity(i1);  
finish();
}
}
```

But I got ERROR every time …

**Log-cat :**

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(328): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method first1
(View) in the activity class com.contactDetails.ContactDetailsActivity for onClick handler on view class 
android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
```

Comment: You forget to add `first1()` method on your `Activity`...as per your logcat..

Comment: This is not a guess game...this is a place where we want to see a code and share our opinion with you...so as @mtetno said CODE PLZ???????

Comment: ya, i am not learner but first u all understand my question. how to run button click event from header file in ANNNNNNNNNNDROID ?

Comment: ContactDetailsActivity class extends HeaderActivity class

Comment: @NikhilsHETH you dont have to create separate class for handling include layout views... you can directly access it from ContactDetailsActivity...

Answer (score 1):

In ContactDetailsActivity.java class you should add below method

```
public void first1(View v)
{
// onlick code 
}
```

Comment: method public void first1(View v) is added in headeractivity.java file and i extend that file in firstactivity.java.

Answer (score 0):

`<include>` tags include all the elements in your root layout. So you can always access them using `findViewById` on your `Activity`.

You could use another way to handle `onClickListener` of your `Button`..

**You don't have to write separate `Activity` for handling include layout views....**

you can directly access that buttons from activity where you have used view (i.e. firstactivity.xml).

Try This..

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i =new Intent(this,firstactivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();   
    }
});

b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i1 =new Intent(this,secondactivity.class);
        startActivity(i1);
        finish();   
    }
});
```

and Remove `onClick` property from both `Button`

Comment: I want to use headeractivity.java in more than single file.

Comment: Ohkk.. instead of declaring methods directly its wise to access onClickListeners for buttons..